# Dispatching a task on a new thread, that can communicate with the parent thread

Tags: java, concurrency, message-passing

I want to dispatch a task on a new thread, and I want this task to notify the parent thread during its various stages of execution. Something like shown below:

```
void unzip(Path source, Path destination, ObserverThread observer) {
  int n = compute number of entries;
  observer.notify("n: " + n);
  while (there are more entries) {
    observer.notify("Unzipping " + name of entry);
    unzip the entry;
  }
  observer.notify("done");
}
```

What will be the standard-library-only solution for this use case? (I want to external dependencies.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using this in Swing then you should use [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) (part of Java). There's an example on [how to publish interim results](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/interim.html) while doing work in the background.

If you're not using Swing then standard java comes with [Executors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) class. You can create a single thread [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) and submit your Runnable to it. It does not offer a way of publishing results in progress but you can still do callbacks manually like you show in the example.

Comment: The link of publishing interim results was useful. Thank you!

Comment: This does not answer the original question though. `SwingWorker`'s `publish` and `process` are `protected`. That and its architecture force one to put all the logic inside the said `SwingWorker`.

Comment: The logic goes in your own class but it does need to extend `SwingWorker`. Additionally you can `addPropertyChangeListener` to a SwingWorker and listeners will be notified when progress is made or you can fire your own events.

Comment: "The logic goes in your own class but it does need to extend SwingWorker." That's what I meant, too. I was referring to my own class extending SwingWorker.

Comment: The issue I have with this model is that processing function still has to reside inside my SwingWorker. I wanted to be able to allow _external_ methods to notify _me_. The method in question here - `unzip` - is in a class named `somestuffhere.io.ZipUtilities`. Currently it does not have the observer parameter I have shown in my example.

Comment: What I had to do was to duplicate the code of `ZipUtilities#unzip` inside my `SwingWorker`. This violates DRY.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way would be to use a [blocking queue of sorts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html). The parent would periodically [`poll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#poll%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) or [`peek`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html#peek%28%29) at the queue in order to receive new messages (interspersed with whatever it does anyway, say, listening for events, etc.)

The "child" thread would simply [`add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html#add%28E%29) its messages to the queue, assuming that the parent removes them in a timely fashion.

I assume here, that parent and child thread must run in parallel, i.e., it is not feasible for the parent thread to block until new messages arrive from the child: what would be the point of having a separate child thread in that case anyway.

Using a blocking queue makes sure, that even if the child produces the messages faster than the parent can consume them, the memory usage stays bounded, and the child will have to wait at some point, until the parent has finally managed to make room in the queue again.

Another approach would be to start discarding messages, when the parent cannot consume them fast enough.

Comment: This is a bit too complicated for my taste, and I am a newbie at Java's concurrency abstractions. Thank you for your answer though!